# How do you retrieve image coordinates from Google Earth Engine Geometry?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, javascript, google-earth-engine

My aim is to convert latitude/longitude coordinates of a GEE ee.Geometry.Polygon object into image coordinates. The boundaries of the image are given by another polygon. The image itself is a sentinel 2 image clipped to the boundary. As the resolution of the image is 10 meters per pixel, I used the following code to retrieve the image coordinates:

```
var bounds = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[3.3079395223880756,51.34383300467846],
                                  [3.361836656032998,51.34383300848277],
                                  [3.415733866051379,51.34383307608253],
                                  [3.415733824454448,51.41112085408156],
                                  [3.3618366972722735,51.41112084166187],
                                  [3.307939497901482,51.411120855830696],
                                  [3.3079395223880756,51.34383300467846]])

var inner_polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[3.380716539818289,51.361941480545184],
                                    [3.380761116743684,51.36191472098738],
                                    [3.3808234979172433,51.361834415151876],
                                    [3.380881499209437,51.36171402006987],
                                    [3.3808235535508273,51.36170511503823],
                                    [3.381006357356093,51.3614732156247],
                                    [3.381068748091356,51.36140636840074],
                                    [3.381126717699261,51.361370651213385],
                                    [3.381215934015894,51.36129485980163],
                                    [3.3812917538786578,51.361201269481676],
                                    [3.3814210252622736,51.360996148219854],
                                    [3.381617248175114,51.360710750962845],
                                    [3.381742064763804,51.36075978564075],
                                    [3.3818357329142734,51.360782080201915],
                                    [3.3819427650716083,51.360786525657986],
                                    [3.382049833303969,51.36077318567795],
                                    [3.38213454359139,51.36074198476364],
                                    [3.3821790793073343,51.36070625403423],
                                    [3.382188030171224,51.36062604692942],
                                    [3.382192462802579,51.360550215942276],
                                    [3.3822147412953063,51.3604699453023],
                                    [3.3822415021078767,51.360403083973246],
                                    [3.3822727355827635,51.36034955208051],
                                    [3.382303941148293,51.360300507122744],
                                    [3.3823485432364975,51.36026926073494],
                                    [3.3824243302612778,51.360246968787294],
                                    [3.3827498385141928,51.360189039223215],
                                    [3.3830976823533483,51.359479985264414],
                                    [3.3831378560449084,51.35948451462555],
                                    [3.3832715487828007,51.359475532944835],
                                    [3.3834811343521283,51.359457713775335],
                                    [3.3834900653614075,51.359502316691945],
                                    [3.3824421426491904,51.361433118076654],
                                    [3.3823173223403282,51.36139746207336],
                                    [3.3822861173599312,51.36145988623646],
                                    [3.3824154446133208,51.36147770800975],
                                    [3.38200075367586,51.36221794809329],
                                    [3.381300660202233,51.36207525834679],
                                    [3.381131194674268,51.36203511921575],
                                    [3.380716539818289,51.361941480545184]])


var north = ee.Geometry.LineString([ee.List(bounds.coordinates().get(0)).get(3),
                                        ee.List(bounds.coordinates().get(0)).get(5)])
var west = ee.Geometry.LineString([ee.List(bounds.coordinates().get(0)).get(5),
                                        ee.List(bounds.coordinates().get(0)).get(6)])

var global_coords = ee.List(inner_polygon.coordinates().get(0))

var image_coords = global_coords.map(function(global_coord){
    var point = ee.Geometry.Point(global_coord)
    return ee.List([point.distance(west).divide(10), point.distance(north).divide(10)])
})

print(bounds)
print(inner_polygon)
print(image_coords)

Map.addLayer(inner_polygon)
Map.addLayer(bounds)
Map.centerObject(bounds)
```

Unfortunately, when I display the image in python the coordinates do not fit perfectly. When I multiply the coordinates by a factor of approximately 1.6 the result is more pleasing:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

poly = Image.new('RGBA', (1200, 1200))
pdraw = ImageDraw.Draw(poly)
coordinates = [[506.8913054655271, 547.273859794789],
               [507.20207873609263, 547.5714965477916],
               [507.63745069432235, 548.4648365033506],
               [508.04276164377217, 549.8042016069392],
               [507.639267215355, 549.9033800196921],
               [508.91506956659225, 552.4830735733655],
               [509.350366035064, 553.2266766368728],
               [509.7545247822053, 553.6239465495947],
               [510.37676528362925, 554.4670092537556],
               [510.9058981966138, 555.5081197297559],
               [511.8085719887429, 557.7899810118598],
               [513.1784789941482, 560.9648351812438],
               [514.047299636047, 560.419059455523],
               [514.699464190546, 560.1708416007166],
               [515.4449108654759, 560.1211797377637],
               [516.1908085343406, 560.2693906458801],
               [516.7811807495409, 560.6163573932212],
               [517.091781836077, 561.0137979760182],
               [517.1550292153986, 561.9061341156093],
               [517.1867571449196, 562.7497919524919],
               [517.3428353673678, 563.6428091907499],
               [517.5299834104551, 564.3866308725723],
               [517.748134881108, 564.9821456411939],
               [517.9660418667575, 565.5277404562387],
               [518.2770585516857, 565.8752891074081],
               [518.805185300541, 566.1231531111932],
               [521.0730873088926, 566.7670149086305],
               [523.5039889075017, 574.6549801771633],
               [523.7837615515125, 574.604507222865],
               [524.7150823271966, 574.7041631535869],
               [526.1751258675347, 574.901984446067],
               [526.2368226301598, 574.4057313267239],
               [518.9158525375329, 552.9264771427167],
               [518.0468730593309, 553.3234152079929],
               [517.8288243979051, 552.6289684143709],
               [518.7293953944867, 552.430438736501],
               [515.8327352920373, 544.1956112702233],
               [510.9582090310453, 545.7844376637312],
               [509.77833251003284, 546.2313215736292],
               [506.8913054655271, 547.273859794789]]
# yellow polygon to display unedited polygon
coordinates = [(coordinate[0], coordinate[1]) for coordinate in coordinates]
pdraw.polygon(coordinates, fill=(255, 255, 0, 255), outline=(255, 255, 255, 64))

# red polygon to display edited polygon
coordinates = [(coordinate[0] * 1.6, coordinate[1] * 1.6) for coordinate in coordinates]
pdraw.polygon(coordinates, fill=(255, 0, 0, 255), outline=(255, 255, 255, 64))
poly.show()
```

Is this an projection issue? Is there a better way to retrieve image coordinates in GEE?

The documentation of ee.Geometry.Point.distance says:

> Returns the minimum distance between two geometries.

What is the unit of length in this context?